# How to create an annimated plot to show daily progression by month

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I want to make the following animation by month, but i cant make that happen.
For this example ill be working with the airquality data

```
p <- ggplot(
  airquality,
  aes(Day, Temp, group = Month, color = factor(Month))
  ) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_viridis_d() +
  labs(x = "Day of Month", y = "Temperature") +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
p
p + 
  geom_point() +
  transition_reveal(Day)
```

which create the gif of the tutorial here: [example of gif](https://www.datanovia.com/en/wp-content/uploads/dn-tutorials/r-tutorial/images/let-data-gradually-appear.gif)

as you can se all the data points appear at the same time, per day.

i have tried this, with no success...

```
# Convert Month to a factor for custom ordering
airquality$Month <- factor(airquality$Month, levels = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9))

# Create a custom ordering variable for animation
airquality$MonthOrder <- as.integer(airquality$Month) - min(as.integer(airquality$Month))


airquality$ID <- seq.int(nrow(airquality))    

# Create the base plot
p <- ggplot(airquality, aes(Day, Temp, group = Month, color = Month)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = factor(ID), group=factor(Month))) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = factor(ID))) +
  scale_color_viridis_d() +
  labs(x = "Day of Month", y = "Temperature") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

p

# Animate the plot with custom ordering
p +
  transition_states(MonthOrder, transition_length = 2, state_length = 1) +
  enter_fade() +
  exit_fade()



p +
  transition_manual(
    frames = factor(ID),
    transition_length = 1,
    state_length = 1
  )
```

Any help to make to make this animation daily, but month per month?
also tested interactions... and nothing....im stuck

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for this.

```
airquality$ID <- seq.int(nrow(airquality))   

p + 
  geom_point() +
  transition_reveal(ID)
```

Despite that in this case works, my real data contained  over 15369 data points. A daily data set between 1979 to 2023, so when the animation was being created the results were messy. For those encountering problems in the future, i would recommend working on a small example and scaling up, once you have something working. Also in my case use the function animate to determine the fps and duration of the gif